# Map keyboard for common paste operation

Tags: keyboard, paste

I want to program a key on my keyboard to paste certain static text when pressed.

For instance, I'd like to program the F12 key so, when pressed, it pastes my email address every time.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: To clarify, I'm not looking to do this inside of a program that I'm writing.  I want a prebuilt utility to help me perform custom key mappings, and assign them to do certain tasks. In this case, paste static text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some excellent free software products that allow you to remap keys and create macros. For Windows, you can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). I've used it before and it can be quite handy for this sort of thing.

It's a very powerful tool and can be a little intimidating to use at first but it's worth taking the time to get to know it. The [Quick Start](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) guide is quite helpful.

If you mean instead, the ability to do this within your own program using C++ or .NET or something, give some more details.

Comment: This is a scriptable language... So he can.